# How to know if a webworker is still running?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am running a webworker from the browser.

From the parent script, I would like to check if the webworker is still running or if it is over.

Comment: You could `postMessage` from the worker at the end of the script and get the parent to handle it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But, maybe the webworker could still be executing some callback functions... or waiting for some event.

Comment: In that case you need to better define *still running*. In either case, you need to call `postMessage` from the last executed callback. The worker has no knowledge of any async functions within it

Comment: I see... Anyway, your solution is good. I was also curious if it was possible without modifying the executed script. According to you, it is not possible?

Answer (score 6):

You should have the web worker post messages about events, like when it is finished work, this way the parent can listen to these messages/events and know when work has completed.  The web worker can even post progress events, this is all up to you to build though, it does not come included.